# Java SE 1.6 in eclipse on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, java

How can i get it to work on OSX snow leopard? When I go new java project in eclipse it has a lib error saying that it is unbound. 1.6 is definetly there as far as i can tell :/
On windows and linux everything just worked but i have been searching for hours now and cannot seems to fnd out how to solve this.

Comment: Which jars you are using in project ?

Comment: none yet. I basically start a new java project and choose SE1.6 and all  get is an src folder. no libs at all.

Comment: Give the correct location of Java where it is installed in eclispe.Problem is because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I installed the latest version instead (helios) and this seems to have fixed the problem.